# How to apply for Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know this might sound like a silly question, but I've spent more than three hours looking for a contact that I should approach when applying for Facebook Graph API.

I'm quite a newbie to computer programming and everything related to it. I've got no friends to ask this question to. It would be perfect if anybody could share his experience of applying for and receiving permission to use Facebook Graph API.

Answer (score 1):

You don´t need to apply somewhere, just [read the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs) and [create apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/).